# Unable to start debugging on web server after creating virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, iis-7

I created new ASP.NET project and in project properties I changed server from IISExpress to local IIS so project url changed from `http: //localhost:51315/` to `http:// localhost/myproject` . I clicked create virtual directory. I received message: Virtual directory successfully created, but when I want to start application I get this error:

```
     Unable to start debugging on web server. The start Url specified is not valid.
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project Properties -> Web, and select option "Specific Page" instead of "Start URL". Start URL does not work with relative URLs which is what you probably had before.